# For loop - display int's in NSMutable Array that are above zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

When i look to run a method if 1 or more int's are higher than zero from my array, what it does now is display only the first value in the array, and it doesn't matter if this value is greater than zero or not.

Any help would be appreciated, my code is below.....

```
-(void)setUpPressedCount{
    self.presscount1 = 0;
    [self.pressCountArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.presscount1]];
    self.presscount2 = 2;
    [self.pressCountArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.presscount2]];
    self.presscount3 = 0;
    [self.pressCountArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.presscount3]];
    self.presscount4 = 0;
    [self.pressCountArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.presscount4]];
    self.presscount5 = 0;
}

-(void)performAction{
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.pressCountArray count]; i++){
        if ([self.pressCountArray objectAtIndex:i >0]) {
            NSLog (@"above zero presscount: %@", [self.pressCountArray objectAtIndex:i]);
            return;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Embrace modern syntax. `[self.pressCountArray addObject:@(presscount1)];`. And `if ([self.pressCountArray[i] intValue] > 0) {`.

Comment: @rmaddy Doesn't apple now want you to use `NSInteger` instead of `int` and therefore you would want the `integerValue`?

Comment: @cabellicar123 It really only matters when you need to support both 32-bit and 64-bit and the values you have might be big enough that it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)setUpPressedCount{
    self.presscount1 = 0;
    [self.pressCountArray addObject:@(self.presscount1)];
    self.presscount2 = 2;
    [self.pressCountArray addObject:@(self.presscount2)];
    self.presscount3 = 0;
    [self.pressCountArray addObject:@(self.presscount3)];
    self.presscount4 = 0;
    [self.pressCountArray addObject:@(self.presscount4)];
    self.presscount5 = 0;
}

-(void)performAction{
    for (NSNumber *num in self.pressCountArray) {
        if (num.integerValue > 0) NSLog (@"above zero presscount: %@", [self.pressCountArray objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
}
```

There were several problems with your code. In Objective-C 2.0, you can use numeric literals instead of what you were using earlier.

An `NSNumber` is an object and cannot be compared using the standard comparison operator. The `integerValue` method gives you the value contained in the `NSNumber` as an `NSInteger`.

I suggest you do some reading on pointers and some basic OOP principals.

Comment: with this tho i am getting the int that is greater than zero, but only the first one if i set more to greater than 0?this s great thank you for you help

Comment: @ggf85 Didn't really understand what you meant by that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the line:

```
if ([self.pressCountArray objectAtIndex:i >0]) {
```

to:

```
if ([[self.pressCountArray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue] > 0]) {
```

Before you were evaluating `i > 0` which could only be `1` or `0` and then using that to get the object. The if statement would run as long as that object was not `null`.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is not good `if ([self.pressCountArray objectAtIndex:i >0]) {` Use instead

```
-(void)performAction{

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.pressCountArray count]; i++){


    if ([[self.pressCountArray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]>0) {
        NSLog (@"above zero presscount: %@", [self.pressCountArray objectAtIndex:i]);
        return;
    }            
}

}
```

Comment: with this tho i am getting the int that is greater than zero, but only the first one if i set more to greater than 0?this s great thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

Change your "if" statement to:

`if ([[self.pressCountArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue] > 0)`